# PHP doesn't redirect to specific page

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I tried to send password to the PHP commands. But when I `echo` it to check condition, it works. But if I don't `echo` but using `headers()` instead , it won't redirect if the password is correct. But if the password isn't correct, it redirects to an error page to show error.

Here is my code.

```
<?php
  //require_once "condb.php";
?>

<?php
  if (isset($_POST['BTN_ENTER']))
  {
    $password=$_POST['password'];
    //echo $password;

    if ($password == "test")
    {
      //echo "ok!";
      header('location:survey.php');
    }else
    {
      //echo "not ok!";
      header('location:error.php');
    }
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Login</title>
  <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <script 
  src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js">
  </script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<style>
div#index 
{
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
</style>

<body style="background-color:#4da6ff;">
  <div align="center" id="index" class="row col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-12 col-xs-12">
  <p style="font-size:32px;color:#66ff33;">Please enter passcode.</p>

  <form method="POST">
    <div align="center" class="row col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xs-12"
style="margin:0 auto;">
      <input type="password" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Please enter a passcode." style="width:40%;height:50%" name="password" autofocus><br>
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg" name="BTN_ENTER"
    style="height:50%;width:20%;">ตกลง
    </button>

  </form>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this?

```
if ($password == "test")
{
  header('Location: survey.php', true, 302);
  die();
}
else
{
  header('Location: error.php', true, 302);
  die();
}
```

Comment: It didn't show any errors. Thank you for your answer. I just forgotten about "$_SESSION".

Answer (score 0):

First thing you should use session or cookie if you want to access the value globally.

Try using javascript snippet for redirection

```
echo "<script>window.location='survey.php';"</script>";
```